# How to get the value of recursive product using negative input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, spyder

because i found it hard to get

take a look:

```
def mult(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    rest = mult(a, b - 1)
    value = a + rest
    return value

prod = int(input('Enter number: '))

print('The product of', prod, 'x', prod, 'is', mult(prod,prod))
```

Comment: Can you fix your formatting? I suspect your `mult` function isn't indented properly.

Comment: @Andy ok i'll fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start with

```
def mult(a, b):
    if b<0: return -mult(a, -b)
```

and continue with the code you have now (assuming the latter's indented properly -- right now it's something of a mess but I'll assume that's merely a formatting issue and the code will work if properly edited:-).

Comment: @RomeliiGaballoAlbia, always happy to help -- remember to **accept** this answer (click on the outline checkmark to the left of the answer) in a few minutes when accepts are allowed!-)